# My infinite loop is not infinite - Python

Tags: python

```
import time
import pyautogui

time.sleep(5)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)

    pyautogui.moveTo(455,620)
    pyautogui.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    pyautogui.moveTo(890,15)
    pyautogui.click()
    
    if KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

I wanted to automate opening and closing a chrome tab endlessly

I tried a while true loop

Comment: What happens when you run your script? Please [edit] your question to elaborate on the problems you have with it. I also recommend you add some output in the script to know when you reach all the important checkpoints in the script.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` is a class, and `print(KeyboardInterrupt)` you'll get `<class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>`. If coerced to boolean, it'll just be `True` (you can confirm it by `print(bool(KeyboardInterrupt))`). So, `if KeyboardInterrupt:` is the same as `if True:`. It will always reach the `break`.

Answer (score 1):

**KeyboardInterrupt** is an Exception, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

There it says:
"Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally Control-C or Delete)."

If you want to catch it, you'll need to use try/except like so:

```
try:
    while True:
        ...
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    ... # don't use break here, as you've already left the loop
```

However, depending on your use-case this is *likely not recommendable*. Once **KeyboardInterrupt** is set, and the program continues to run, **this may/will create unpredictable execution behaviour further down the line.** For instance,

## Consider these examples:

```
try:
    while True:
        print(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(2)
while True:
    try:
        print(3)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(4)
        break
```

Prints ones until interrupt is hit, then a single 2, then threes until next interrupt hit, then a single 4 and exits.

and now the same, but with an additional if-clause

```
try:
    while True:
        print(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(2)
while True:
    try:
        print(3)
        if KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(5)
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(4)
        break
```

Instead of printing lots of threes in the second loop, it hits the if-clause asking about the state of KeyboardInterrupt and since this is set, it breaks immediately (without the pressing of any key).

You *could* use it continuously within try/except blocks, but (from the docs):

> **Note:** Catching a KeyboardInterrupt requires special consideration. Because
> it can be raised at unpredictable points, it may, in some
> circumstances, leave the running program in an inconsistent state. **It**
> **is generally best to allow KeyboardInterrupt to end the program as**
> **quickly as possible or avoid raising it entirely.** (See Note on Signal
> Handlers and Exceptions.)

Answer (score 1):

KeyboardInterrupt is an exception, so your code should be:

```
import time
import pyautogui

time.sleep(5)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(5)

        pyautogui.moveTo(455,620)
        pyautogui.click()

        time.sleep(5)

        pyautogui.moveTo(890,15)
        pyautogui.click()
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt: break
```

In addition, for KeyboardInterrupt to work, you need to press ctrl+c **directly** in the console, so the console window must be active at this moment